# HTML: Nest ' in string

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to nest a ' character within an input. Something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="breakme" value="" onfocus='alert(\'1\');' autofocus="true" />
```

I understand that you can do something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="breakme" value="" onfocus="alert('1');" autofocus="true" />
```

but I specifically need to do it with a nested '

**EDIT** to make it clear, I am specifically trying to demonstrate a XXS attack, so there can be no other script, and it MUST be done within this input. I am injecting into another input

```
<input type="text" name="breakme" value="<?php echo @$_POST['breakme'] ?>">
```

so it cannot be a " and must use '. Because of what i want to inject (a call such as `'google.com?' + 'hi'` I need to be able to nest '

Comment: Why do you need to have nested quotes?

Comment: Just use `addEventListener` in a script and drop the `onfocus` attribute.

Comment: That won't work. It has to be done in the input. See edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on*` attributes are completely normal HTML, so you can use a character reference like `&#39;` or `&#x27;` to encode an apostrophe:

```
<input type="hidden" name="login" value="" onfocus='alert(&#39;1&#39;);' autofocus="true" />
```

`&apos;` is also defined by HTML5, but be aware that it doesn’t work in IE8.

Comment: That did it. Just had to find the right special character. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does not:

```
<input type="hidden" name="login" value="" onfocus="alert('1\u0027');" autofocus="true" />
```

Just works?

Comment: It does not, but a possibly important note is that I am trying to demonstrate a XXS attack, so this will be loaded into another input field

Comment: The unicode version works? it does output a single quote, i m trying to figure out what do you mean by nested.

Comment: The unicode didn't work either. The edit makes it more clear, but it was loading incorrectly